# Android - How to set interface color based on return value from if else statement

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

In my file activity (java), I had if else statement which hold value of (condition) and the value need to pass to the interface. After the value passed to the interface then the color of the interface should be based on the value (condition).

The condition are "normal", "hypertension", "blood pressure stage 1" and "blood pressure stage 2".

Example, If the the condition is "normal" then the color of the interface should be green.

This is if else code:

```
if (iBPM >= 60 && iBPM < 79) {
            condition = "Normal resting heart rate";
        }
else if (iBPM >= 80 && iBPM <= 89) {
            condition = "Prehypertension";
        }
else if (iBPM >= 90 && iBPM <= 99) {
            condition = "High Blood Pressure \n (Hypertension) stage 1";
        }
else if (iBPM >= 100 && iBPM <= 110) {
            condition = "High Blood Pressure \n (Hypertension) stage 2";
        }
        txtCON.setText("" + condition);
```

Below is the code for the condition at layout. The id is **tvCondition**. The id is used to get the value of the condition from the file activity (java).

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="--"
    android:id="@+id/tvCondition"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtLabe2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Basically the color of the interface is blue because I set it as default color for the interface.  I put the index color at the top **#737CA1**.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="#737CA1">
```

Back to the questions, How to change the color of the interface based on the value if else statement at the activity file.

thank you,
faizal

Comment: additionally to `condition` you could `conditionColor`, type `int`, and you could change its value accordingly to the `if`. Then you call `textView.setTextColor(conditionColor)`  just before calling `setText`

Comment: I assign TextView colorBG and set colorBG to the id "layout". as you can see at the last code, the id is layout and the id in the LinearLayout. 

I type this code, "colorBG = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.layout);" and it return error..

@Blackbelt

Comment: actually I dont want to set text color but I want to set background color based on the condition.

@Blackbelt

Comment: Then call setBackgroundColor on your view's object

Comment: I want to try set text color. you said type is int, then I set: int conditionColor; in IF statement, I write code conditionColor= #76ff03; it return error. @Blackbelt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. But this answer is to change the text color based on the IF ELSE STATEMENT from java file, not to change the background color

step1:

```
private static TextView txtCOL = null;
private static TextView txtCON = null;
```

step2:

```
txtCON = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCondition);
txtCOL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCondition);
```

step3:

```
String condition = null;
int conditionColor;
```

step4:

```
if (iBPM >= 50 && iBPM < 60) {
            condition = "Low / weak heart rate";
            conditionColor = Color.parseColor("#2196f3"); //blue
        }
        else if (iBPM >= 60 && iBPM < 79) {
            condition = "Normal resting heart rate";
            conditionColor = Color.parseColor("#689f38"); //green
        }
        else if (iBPM >= 80 && iBPM <= 89) {
            condition = "PreHypertension";
            conditionColor = Color.parseColor("#ffeb3b"); //yellow
        }
        else if (iBPM >= 90 && iBPM <= 99) {
            condition = "High Blood Pressure \n (Hypertension) stage 1";
            conditionColor = Color.parseColor("#ff9800"); //orange
        }
        else if (iBPM >= 100 && iBPM <= 110) {
            condition = "High Blood Pressure \n (Hypertension) stage 2";
            conditionColor = Color.parseColor("#ff5722"); //deep orange
        }
```

step5:

```
//call textView.setTextColor(conditionColor) just before calling textVIew.setText(condition)   
txtCOL.setTextColor(conditionColor);
txtCON.setText("" + condition);
```

Done.